# Subtract values in different records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the MTTF (mean time to failure) in this table.

```
     machine_type_id    time    machine_id  event_type
      275                  0    97957590    0
      11148         64082917976 97957590    1
      11160         64508629318 97957590    0
      11565         94842321864 97957590    1
      11567         95269562076 97957590    0
      34517       2334183699633 97957590    1
      34519      2334580893038  97957590    0
```

Where, `event_type = 0`  is when machine added or on, and `event_type= 1` is when machine failed. `MTTF= total downtime /number of failure`.

My SQL script has problem in subtracting the time failure  from time added in right sequences. For example, It could subtract resent failure with all times that machine added to pool. While it should subtract from last time that machine was added the pool. Another issues is the final stage when you divided the total downtime from number of failure.

My SQL script is

```
select  o.machine_id, sum(o.timefailure- t.timeadded)/count(o.event_type) as MTTF
from 
    (
    select machine_id, machine_type_id ,time as timeadded 
    from machine_events 
    where event_type= 0 and machine_id=97957590 
    ) as t
INNER JOIN
    (
    select  machine_id,machine_type_id, event_type,time as timefailure
    from machine_events 
    where event_type = 1 and machine_id=97957590 
    ) as o
on o.machine_id=t.machine_id
where  o.timefailure- t.timeadded  <> 0 and  o.machine_type_id > t.machine_type_id 
group by o.machine_id
```

I will put simple data for test

```
--INSERT INTO VALUES (   275,   0, 111, 0 );    
--INSERT INTO VALUES ( 11148,   4, 111, 1 );
--INSERT INTO VALUES ( 11160,   7, 111, 0 );
--INSERT INTO VALUES ( 11565,   17, 111, 1 );
--INSERT INTO VALUES ( 11567,   20, 111, 0 );
--INSERT INTO VALUES ( 34517,   40, 111, 1 );
--INSERT INTO VALUES ( 34519,   50, 111, 0 );
```

Total downtime here (4+10+20). So `MTTF= Totaldowntime/number of failure`

Comment: What does this means:  last time that machine was added the pool" ?

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved? (In the subqueries.)

Comment: Pool means to added to data center

Comment: GROUP BY is removed, it was for some shot

Comment: Your explanation is not clear. Please post current results and desired results (i.e., show don't tell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE deleteme_tbl;

CREATE TABLE deleteme_tbl
(
    machine_type_id    INT
  , time               INT
  , machine_id         INT
  , event_type         INT
);

INSERT INTO deleteme_tbl VALUES (   275,             0, 97957590, 0 );    
INSERT INTO deleteme_tbl VALUES ( 11148,   64082917976, 97957590, 1 );
INSERT INTO deleteme_tbl VALUES ( 11160,   64508629318, 97957590, 0 );
INSERT INTO deleteme_tbl VALUES ( 11565,   94842321864, 97957590, 1 );
INSERT INTO deleteme_tbl VALUES ( 11567,   95269562076, 97957590, 0 );
INSERT INTO deleteme_tbl VALUES ( 34517, 2334183699633, 97957590, 1 );
INSERT INTO deleteme_tbl VALUES ( 34519, 2334580893038, 97957590, 0 );

COMMIT;

WITH
    addset
    AS
        (SELECT machine_type_id
              , time
              , machine_id
              , event_type
           FROM deleteme_tbl
          WHERE event_type = 0),
    dropset
    AS
        (SELECT machine_type_id
              , time
              , machine_id
              , event_type
           FROM deleteme_tbl
          WHERE event_type = 1),
    finalset
    AS
        (SELECT addset.*
              , (SELECT MIN (time)
                   FROM dropset
                  WHERE dropset.machine_id = addset.machine_id
                    AND dropset.time > addset.time)
                    AS time_off
           FROM addset)
  SELECT machine_id, SUM (time_off - time) / COUNT (*) mttf
    FROM finalset
GROUP BY machine_id
```

Comment: Brilliant, @brianleach. Only issue left is when you divide it by number of failure. 'COUNT (*) mttf' does not represent the number of failure

Comment: count(*), is total number of adding from addset. It should be total number failure from dropset. Still trying to fix it

Comment: It shouldn't matter, there is a one-to-one correspondence between the two. You can't have a failure without the machine being added on, and you can't calculate a mean time to failure with a failure. I had a typo in the dropset clause, event_type filter s/b 1, not 0.  I take that back, the machine could be taken off-line without failure, in which case there are two add events and only 1 failure event, in which case you need to know when it was taken off line, which is not in your data set. Given your data set, there is a one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: Yes, machine can be removed for other events. you are right. However, I put an simple example in the post, to calculate the MTTF. Now should we divide the total downtime by # of failure or added. Thanks @BrianLeach, hope I understand your comment